# browser websocket is not responding back with pong

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have used ws(nodejs websocket library) for server side websocket, also server is pinging clients for pong frame. If server do not receives a pong frame within 20 seconds, it terminates those client connections.

What i have noticed is that while server is sending contineous data to the browser, browser is taking some time to replay back with the pong frame. So if the data transfer is huge, browser is unable to respond back with pong frame within 20 second and since server has 20 second window it will disconnect the browser socket.

Comment: Why should there be a ping/pong if data is being sent?  This is all going over TCP, so the packets are getting ACK'ed at the lower layer anyway.  This sounds like a bad design of the server.

Comment: @brad i have few doubts. 
1. how server will know if the data is being transfered ot not ? 
2. so should i do ping/pong only in case of no data transfer ?

Comment: Look into how TCP works.  There's no need for you to do ping/pong except to verify that the connection is still alive if data hasn't been sent in awhile.  Additionally, this sort of are-you-still-there packet can be sent via TCP by sending a packet with no data.  (But, not everything implements this, so that's probably why there's an application layer ping/pong in the web socket specification.)  What's probably happening in your case is that you're probably buffering a ton of Web Socket frames to send, and the client hasn't gotten your ping frame yet.